# How to check if a node exists using XMLConfigurtion in apache common?

Tags: java, apache, configuration, apache-commons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<processor>
    <user_config>
        <a>xxxxx</a>    
    </user_config>
</processor>
```

I want to check if the user_config exist in this xml config file, is there any method I can use in org.apache.common.XMLConfiguration?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem with:

```
if(configuration.configurationsAt( "user_config" ).size() > 0 ) {
    //it exists
}
```

I don't like this solution. If anybody knows a better solution -> Please share.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure about the XMLConfiguration you could use the org.apache.xpath to check if the user_config exists or parse it to a DOM object from either a string, inputstream or file and check it that way.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse("");
```

Answer (score 0):

`boolean containsKey(String key)` would solve the problem: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration.html#containsKey(java.lang.String)

Comment: containsKey doesn't work with nodes without a value like the above user_config, it returns false for that